# How to allow put method in apache2

Tags: apache

The put method is being tested in apache2 under the following enviroment.

---

- OS : Ubuntu 16.04
- Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
- Server built:   2018-06-07T19:43:03
- WAS : Python CGI

---

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
...
<Directory "/var/www/html">
#       Dav On
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
        Options ExecCGI
        <LimitExcept GET POST PUT OPTIONS>
                Order Allow,Deny
                Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
...
```

---

PUT Method is allowed as  for apache2.conf, but PUT Method is not allowed if you try OPTIONS Method on the root page.
And sending a PUT request results in an Method not allow error of 405.

Setup of all other methods is possible, but PUT and DELETE are not possible.
Is Apache2 the default security setting?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it seems apache 2.4 limits those requests, I got it working by adding this to an .htaccess file on the webdir folder:

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
# Deprecated apache 2.2 syntax:
# Order Allow,Deny
# Allow from all
# Apache > 2.4 requires:
Require all granted
</Limit>
```